# Datatables paging not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a simple DataTable. This is my init method.

```
var oTable = $('#detailsTable').dataTable({
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sProcessing": "Laddar...",
                    "sLengthMenu": "Visa _MENU_ rader",
                    "sZeroRecords": "Inga matchande resultat funna",
                    "sInfo": "Visar _START_ till _END_ av totalt _TOTAL_ rader",
                    "sInfoEmpty": "Visar 0 till 0 av totalt 0 rader",
                    "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrerade från totalt _MAX_ rader)",
                    "sInfoPostFix": "",
                    "sSearch": "Sök:",
                    "sUrl": "",
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sFirst": "Första",
                        "sPrevious": "Föregående",
                        "sNext": "Nästa",
                        "sLast": "Sista"
                    }
                },
                "aaSorting": [],
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "bStateSave": true,
                "aLengthMenu": [
                     [10, 20, 50, -1],
                     [10, 20, 50, "Alla"]
                ]
            });
```

The paging works, when i hit page 3 the data is changed, however page 1 is still marked in the paging GUI.
Any ideas? Cant see anything wrong in my code.

Comment: Perhaps you can create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Tobias Olofsson,Different datatable version  has class e.g current or paginate_active for pagination,
in your case it is missing when you clicked on page number you can inspect with firebug here http://www.datatables.net/examples/styling/no-classes.html